# How to fix my partial in order it updates when model updates?

Tags: angularjs

In my HTML, I have a series of tab, that changes the content of the partial as follows:

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li
                ng-repeat="project in projects"
                ng-class="currentProject==$index?'active':''">
                <a ng-click="setProject($index)"    >{{project.title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <h2>{{project.title}}</h2>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ng-class="getPage()=='/project/status' ?'active':''"><a ng-href="#/project/status"  >Résumé</a></li>
            <li ng-class="getPage()=='/project/graphs/burndown' ?'active':''"><a ng-href="#/project/graphs/burndown"    >Graphe RÀF</a></li>
            <li ng-class="getPage()=='/project/details'?'active':''"><a ng-href="#/project/details" >Liste détails</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- partial content -->
        <section id="partial" ng-view></section>
```

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.setProject = function(id) {
    $scope.currentProject = id;
    $scope.project = $scope.projects[id];
    //$scope.$apply($scope.project);
}
```

The issue I face is that when I switch the current project by tapping on one of the first tabs, though {{}} are updated in the HTML, the partial itself is not updated. 
I suspect I have to call $apply in some ways, but I'm confused: where and how? 
As you can see in the controller method setProject() I ran some tests without success.

[UPDATE] The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/Zk2qa/21/

Comment: ng-view creates a new scope like ng-repeat so my guess is a scoping issue which could probably be solved with dot notation. Cannot really say more without seeing more code. A plunker would be nice.

Comment: I added a fiddle @user2847643

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example is that you're calling `$scope.setProject(0)` in your controller.  All your templates use the same controller, and when you navigate to a new route, the controller runs again and resets the project to 0 (you can see this happening if you watch the console while you navigate around).  Take out the `$scope.setProject(0)` and it should work.  Realistically, each of your templates would probably have a separate controller, as would your top level navigation.

### Update

Responding to your question below.  I am still learning Angular myself and am by no means an expert, so take everything I say with a grain of salt.

A controller is basically the brain behind the view.  It prepares the data, and handles the interface logic.  The user interfaces with the view, and the view interfaces with the controller, with interfaces with the rest of the application.

In your case, you have three views that all use the same data.  But they do different things (even if all they do differently is display the same data in different ways).  Each view has a different purpose, and each should have a different brain/controller.  Maybe one view has a sortable grid, and another view has a button for generating a pdf (and if they don't now, maybe they will next month).  You don't want to be mixing all the logic for all the views together.  It will become a mess and hard to work with.

There are a few ways to make your data available to your controllers.  If your data is self-contained on the client (which it sounds like it is in your case), you could stuff it into a value or constant like this:

```
app.constant('projects', [
{   id: 0,
    name: 'Proj1',      
    title: 'First project',
    description: ['First project description']
},
{   id:0,
    name: 'Proj2',      
    title: 'Second project',
    description: ['Second project description']
}
]);
```

or even just assign it to the $rootScope.  That might work fine, but it doesn't really feel right.  And one day you may decide that you want to load your data from a remote server afterall.  It probably makes more sense to put your data access into a service.

```
app.service('dataService', function(){
    return{
        getData: function(){
            return  [
                {   id: 0,
                    name: 'Proj1',      
                    title: 'First project',
                    description: ['First project description']
                },
                {   id:1,
                    name: 'Proj2',      
                    title: 'Second project',
                    description: ['Second project description']
                }
            ];
        }
    };
});
```

Here, the service returns a `getData` function which returns your list of projects.  Right now, it just returns the hard-coded array of projects, but your could also put an $http call in there to pull the data from a server somewhere.  If you decide to make that change some day, you won't have to change a bunch of code in your controllers, because all they have access to is `getData` and they don't care where the data comes from.

Your controllers also need to know which project is selected, so it makes sense to use a service for that as well.  Here's my navService:

```
app.service('navService', function(){
    selectedProject = {};
    return {
        getProject: function(){        
            return selectedProject;
        },
        
        setProject: function(project){
            selectedProject = project;
        }
    };
});
```

It just keeps track of which project is selected, and provides getter and setter functions.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk2qa/23/).

Hope that all made sense.  I would encourage anyone to correct me if anything I wrote is not correct.

Comment: Got it! And you come across one of my questioning. As I'm progressing thru the angularjs knowledge while developing a large app (coming from legacy tech), I wonder when one should decide to create a controller (what are the basic criteria)? And, then, what are the benefits vs disadvantages? For example, the three partials require the same model (basically the projects database, which is currently held in the client code (no remote server for this app). And how is ti possible to share the projects thru all routes?